# Using SwiftUI with Core Data

Tags: core-data, swiftui

SwiftUI tables require a binding to an array storing the entirety of your model objects in memory. For small datasets, the tradeoff of convenience for performance makes sense. But for datasets with tens/hundreds of thousands of values, the old-school approach to rendering tables through queries to a datasource still seems like the way to go. (Consider a simple dictionary/thesaurus app.).

Is there a way to implement dataSource-style/CoreData-backed tables within SwiftUI?

Comment: Since there was no comment, I can only assume that my answer below was not appropriate for some reason, so I deleted it.

If you are still looking for some hints and tips on how to use CoreData with SwiftUI and need a place to start, check out my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348127/swiftui-coredata-master-detail-with-editing-xcode-11-beta-5/57533494#57533494

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List does not require an `Array`. The `Data` must conform to the [`RandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection) protocol.
This could also be your `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```swift
extension List {
    /// Creates a List that computes its rows on demand from an underlying
    /// collection of identified data.
    @available(watchOS, unavailable)
    public init<Data, RowContent>(
        _: Data,
        selection _: Binding<Selection>?,
        rowContent _: @escaping (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> RowContent
    ) where Content == ForEach<Data, HStack<RowContent>>,
        Data: RandomAccessCollection,
        RowContent: View,
        Data.Element:
        Identifiable

    /// Creates a List that computes its rows on demand from an underlying
    /// collection of identified data.
    @available(watchOS, unavailable)
    public init<Data, RowContent>(
        _: Data,
        selection _: Binding<Selection>?,
        action _: @escaping (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> Void,
        rowContent _: @escaping (Data.Element.IdentifiedValue) -> RowContent
    ) where Content == ForEach<Data, Button<HStack<RowContent>>>,
        Data: RandomAccessCollection,
        RowContent: View, Dat
}
```

Comment: Hello Ugo, I dont't get how the code you postet helps ? What are the next steps ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the reason of using ForEach() for loops in SwiftUI, so the view can control how many elements needs to instantiate to fill the screen.

And the Array from a Core Data fetch request probably doesn't contains all the objects in memory, they only get instantiated when they are accessed.