# SwiftUI / CoreData / Master / Detail (with editing) / Xcode 11 - Beta 5

Tags: core-data, swiftui, xcode11

Working on a sample app.  The goal is to have a list pulled up from CoreData in a Master, and then click on one to go to a detail, where you can edit the information and save.  When you edit the "name" in the detail, it not only updates the detail to reflect the change, but it also reflects the change on the master as well.  I've tried numerous ways to accomplish this, but so far have not come up with an answer.

```
// Code generation is turned OFF in the xcdatamodeld file

public class EntityName: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
   @NSManaged public var name: String
   @NSManaged public var active: Bool
}

extension EntityName {
    static func allEntityNameFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<EntityName> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<EntityName> = EntityName.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<EntityName>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        return request
   }
}


struct MasterView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: EntityName.allEntityNameFetchRequest()) var allEntityNames: FetchedResults<EntityName>


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.allEntityNames) { entityName in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(entityName: entityName)) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(entityName.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(String(entityName.active))
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        // Just want to populate the Core Data to have a few to work with
        if self.allEntityNames.count == 0 {
            for _ in 1...3 {
                let newEntry = EntityName(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                newEntry.name = "New Entry"

                try! self.managedObjectContext.save()
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

struct DetailView: View {

   var entityName = EntityName()

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text("Name: \(entityName.name)")
           Text("Active: \(String(entityName.active))")

           // What I'd like to do now:
              //TextField("", text: $entityName.name)
              //Toggle(isOn: $entityName.active)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've been working on exactly what you want, namely a sample app that exercises all of the core data use cases that I use in my own apps.  I was very close to finishing it in Beta 2, but Betas 3, 4, and 5 have each broken various pieces of it.  I will post it to Github as soon as the SwiftUI API's get fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As promised, here is a link to sample SwiftUI program that uses CoreData. The current version compiles and runs on the GM release. It does not use the new @FetchRequest property wrapper because it does not suit all of my needs.  I wrote a CoreDataDataSource class that does basically the same thing plus a lot more.

https://github.com/Whiffer/SwiftUI-Core-Data-Test

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm marking this as correct, because it does everything that one would want to accomplish with CoreData.  Trapper's answer is correct with the DetailView, but the issue I've been having is that the MasterView doesn't update properly when you just use a binding on the DetailView.  I'm not sure why that is.  I went one step further with Chuck's Test project and added a lastName attribute, adding it all the places it was needed.  The List view still updates as it should, something I could not accomplish with the code I posted above with the change Trapper suggested.

Comment: Part of the problem with getting CoreData's NSManagedObjects to play nicely with SwiftUI and Combine is that they are not "classic" Swift objects.  Besides the caching and faulting done under the covers by the CoreData framework, NSManagedObjects don't actually "change" until you save the NSManagedObjectContext.  Then bring iCloud into the picture and your objects will change or get deleted asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the entity in DetailView to the entity passed in from MasterView. Declare it like `@Binding var entityName: EntityName`

Answer (score 0):

As @trapper explained, the `entityName` has to be bound the the `MasterView`.

Updates are reflected when you add `@ObservedObject` in the `DetailView` as follows:

```swift
@ObservedObject var entityName:EntityName
```