# Pass managed object to view as binding

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Question:** What is the clean way of passing an object retrieved from the managed object context via fetch request to a view that expects a binding?

**Example**

The parent view has a list of elements retrieved from a fetch request:

```
struct EventView: View {

    @FetchRequest( /* some fetch request */)
    var events: FetchedResults<Event>

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                ForEach(events) { event in
                    // How to pass the event as a binding?
                    EventListEntry(event: event) // event is not a binding 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The EventListEntry expects an Event object as binding:

```
struct EventListEntry: View {

    @Binding var event: Event

    var body: some View {
        // UI definition 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a `Binding`, and not just a `let event: Event`? Or maybe you want it to be an `@ObservedObject` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614564/swiftui-use-binding-with-core-data-nsmanagedobject)

Comment: Why does `event` need to be a binding, it's a class so it can be changed anyway.

Comment: as mentioned, change `@Binding var event: Event` to `@ObservedObjectvar event: Event`, and that is a clean way of passing your objects from the FetchedResults.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164583/how-do-i-update-a-coredata-object-in-a-detail-view-correctly/68347755#68347755